# Removing a line from a file via button action

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

YES, I have searched the method to remove a specific line via comparing&matching, but mine is different from the situations I've searched, and the wrong action takes place.

The code here is the `actionPerformed` for the button `btnRemove`. What it does is it removes the selected cell from the table, and also is meant to remove the corresponding cell (string) value from the file `Activities.dat`

However, what happens is that the code makes the **entire** file removed and blank, leaving 1 empty line, not just the line I want removed.

```
btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {

                    //Execute when button is pressed
                    int row = table.getSelectedRow(); 
                    int column = table.getSelectedColumn();

                    if (row >= 0) {
                        if (column >=0) {

                        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                         {
                            table.setValueAt("", row, column);     
                         }
                        }
                    }

                File file1 = new File("Activities.dat");
                try
                {
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));

                    Object lineToRemove = table.getValueAt(row, column);
                    lineToRemove.toString(); 
                    System.out.print(lineToRemove);

                    String currentLine;

                    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                    // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();

                    Object lineToRemove = table.getValueAt(row, column);
                    lineToRemove.toString();                                        

                    if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
                        writer.write(currentLine);
                    }                                                               
                     writer.close();

                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(ActivityScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
               }
           });
```

Comment: What do you need that `for` loop for?

Comment: The `for` loop is used for the part when removing a selected cell from the table. But I'm not an expert with java; is it unnecessary to have it there?

Comment: The `for` loop is just doing `table.setValueAt("", row, column)` 5 times, so I think it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a duplicate `lineToRemove` in your `while` loop. It will also be better if you changed the type of `line` to `String` and assign the value of `table.getValueAt(row, column).toString()` to it (and don't change it afterwards). Also, you're setting the value of [`row`, `column`] *before* you get it. You will be searching for `""` (searching for nothing if not a very good idea). Try doing something like this:

```
    btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Execute when button is pressed
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
            if (row >= 0) {
                if (column >= 0) {
                    File file1 = new File("Activities.dat");
                    File temp = new File(file1.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp"); // temp file
                    PrintWriter writer = null;
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    try {
                        writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp)), false);
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
                        String lineToRemove = table.getValueAt(row, column).toString();
                        System.out.print(lineToRemove);
                        String currentLine;
                        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                            if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove))
                                continue;
                            writer.println(currentLine);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ActivityScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (reader != null)
                                reader.close();
                            if (writer != null) {
                                writer.flush();
                                writer.close();
                                file1.delete(); // delete the old one
                                temp.renameTo(file1); // make temp same as original
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    table.setValueAt("", row, column);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: When I remove the `getName()` from my code, I get an error saying `no suitable method found for getLogger(Class <ActivityScreen>) etc....`

So I tried with the `getName()` to see what would happn, but the result was the same; `Activites.dat` gets replaced by a single, empty line

Comment: Aah right...but @Java, I think I found the answer(or half an answer, really); I realised that `BufferedWriter`'s append mode wasn't set as `true`, which caused the entire file to become blank!!

....right? I don't know if I'm correct or not

Comment: @Geuni Append works, but it appends the result to the end (not exactly what you want). I finally found the problem: the writer and reader were the same file, and they were reading and writing at the same time, causing your file to go blank. There needs to be a temporary file for the writer - see my edit. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm! :) Thank you so much for helping me until the end!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Leave the file as it is until the line you want to remove, then copy the rest of the file from the end of your removed part to the end of file from the point you started removing.

Pseudo code:

```
String line = "line I want to remove";
RandomAccessFile raf = openRandomAccessFile();

while(!line.equals(raf.readLine())) {
    //just going to the point we want
}

long beginOfTheRemovingPointer = raf.getFilePointer()-size of removed line;
raf.seek(beginOfTheRemovingPointer);
raf.write(from beginOfTheRemovingPointer+size of removed line until the end);
raf.setLength(new length);
```

The `RandomAccessFile` methods exist. Just take a look at the API to know what they do exactly.